# is dash a special character in R regex?

Tags: r, regex

Despite reading the [help page of R regex](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/regex.html)

> Finally, to include a literal -, place it first or last (or, for perl
>   = TRUE only, precede it by a backslash).

I can't understand the difference between

```
grepl(pattern=paste("^thing1\\-",sep=""),x="thing1-thing2")
```

and

```
grepl(pattern=paste("^thing1-",sep=""),x="thing1-thing2")
```

Both return TRUE. Should I escape or not here? What is the best practice?

Comment: `-` is special within character classes, where to match letters or `-` you would have to write `[-a-zA-z]` but I don't think it is outside of them. That section of the help page seems to be discussing character classes specifically.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The hyphen is mostly a *normal* character in regular expressions.

You do not need to escape the hyphen outside of a character class; it has no special meaning.

Within a character class `[ ]` you can place a hyphen as the **first** or **last** character in the range. If you place the hyphen anywhere else you need to escape it in order to add it to your class.

Examples:

```
grepl('^thing1-', x='thing1-thing2')
[1] TRUE
grepl('[-a-z]+', 'foo-bar')
[1] TRUE
grepl('[a-z-]+', 'foo-bar')
[1] TRUE
grepl('[a-z\\-\\d]+', 'foo-bar')
[1] TRUE
```

**Note:** It is more common to find a hyphen placed **first** or **last** within a character class.

Answer (score 8):

To see what it means for `-` to have a special meaning inside of a character class (and how putting it last gives it its literal meaning), try the following:

```
grepl("[w-y]", "x")
# [1] TRUE
grepl("[w-y]", "-")
# [1] FALSE
grepl("[wy-]", "-")
# [1] TRUE
grepl("[wy-]", "x")
# [1] FALSE
```

Answer (score 1):

They are both matching the exact same text in these instances. I.e.:

```
x <- "thing1-thing2"
regmatches(x,regexpr("^thing1\\-",x))
#[1] "thing1-"
regmatches(x,regexpr("^thing1-",x))
#[1] "thing1-"
```

Using a `-` is a special character in certain situations though, for specifying ranges of values, such as characters between `a` and `z` when specifed inside `[]`, e.g.:

```
regmatches(x,regexpr("[a-z]+",x))
#[1] "thing"
```