# Split string recursively

Tags: regex, r, string, mapreduce

Say I have text like this:

```
pattern = "This_is some word/expression I'd like to parse:intelligently(using special symbols-like '.')"
```

The challenge is how to split it into words, using word separators from the

```
c(" ","-","/","\\","_",":","(",")",".",",")
```

family.

**Desired result:**

```
"This" "is" "some" "word" "expression" "I'd" "like" "to" "parse" "intelligently" "using" "special" "symbols" "like"
```

**Methods**:

I could do `sapply` or `for` loop using:

```
 keywords = unlist(strsplit(pattern," "))
 keywords = unlist(strsplit(keywords,"-"))
```

# etc.

**Question:**

But what's the solution using `Reduce(f, x, init, accummulate=TRUE)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use option `perl = TRUE` and then split on punctuation or space

```
> strsplit(pattern, '[[:punct:]]|[[:space:]]', perl = TRUE)
[[1]]
 [1] "This"          "is"            "some"          "word"          "expression"   
 [6] "I"             "d"             "like"          "to"            "parse"        
[11] "intelligently" "using"         "special"       "symbols"       "like"         
[16] ""
```

Comment: Actually I don't mind "I"+"d" vs "I'd". For simplicity sake, I will edit the desired output in the question

Comment: @DanielKrizian, then that makes the problem *much* simpler (as is seen with this answer).

Answer (score 5):

You shouldn't need `Reduce` here. You should be able to do something like the following:

```
splitters <- c(" ","/","\\","_",":","(",")",".",",","-") # dash should come last
pattern <- paste0("[", paste(splitters, collapse = ""), "]")
string <- "This_is some word/expression I'd like to parse:intelligently(using special symbols-like '.')"
strsplit(string, pattern)[[1]]
#  [1] "This"          "is"            "some"          "word"         
#  [5] "expression"    "I'd"           "like"          "to"           
#  [9] "parse"         "intelligently" "using"         "special"      
# [13] "symbols"       "like"          "'"             "'"
```

Note that a `-` in a regex character class should come first or last, so I've edited your vector of "splitters" accordingly. Also, you may want to add a `+` at the end of your "pattern" in case you want to collapse, say, multiple spaces into one.

Comment: @DavidArenburg, it's closer now.

Comment: very helpful in case one needs to add customization to the other answer

Comment: any reason why "dash should come last" ?

Comment: @DanielKrizian, see [this Q & A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24154248/is-dash-a-special-character-in-r-regex) about a dash with regex.

Answer (score 2):

I'd go with (It will keep `"I'd"` together)

```
strsplit(pattern, "[^[:alnum:][:digit:]']")
## [[1]]
##  [1] "This"          "is"            "some"          "word"          "expression"    "I'd"           "like"          "to"            "parse"        
## [10] "intelligently" "using"         "special"       "symbols"       "like"          "'"             "'"
```